# How do you get more detail out of the automated disk defragger?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

It is somewhat nice that Microsoft decided to automate the disk defragger.  But today my system seemed kind of slow so I thought I would run the Analyze portion to get a report particularly on the fragments per file.  But at first glance it appears you cannot do that without first wiping out the present schedule.  I also found it Disabled and that it had not run for ~4 weeks and I know that nobody in this house disabled it.  Well I changed it back to Ready and forced it to run immediately but the Application Event just said it completed successfully.  Does anybody know how to tweak this thing so it gives out more info without wiping out the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Run it from commandline

```
defrag C: /V /U /H
```

flag /U /V tell defrag to display some details (% and passes)

Comment: Windows 7 will not let me run it from a command line - says I have insufficient privilege and I have administrator privilege.

Comment: @Walt - you may need to use the elevated administrator account. Tutorial here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html

Comment: Yes I just Googled that out a few minutes ago.  Thanks.